# How best to Count(*) with a CASE STATEMENT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

The following SQL (on SQL Server) returns an error of:

> Incorrect syntax near '*'

Is there something inherently wrong with using the following SELECT statement?:

```
SELECT
COUNT(CASE WHEN <conditions> THEN * ELSE NULL END) as conditionalcountall
FROM TABLE
```

I tried this variation which also failed:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN <conditions> THEN COUNT(*) ELSE NULL END as conditionalcountall
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: This is a great place to start: [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tend to like sum()

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN <conditions> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as conditionalcountall
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: This is the standard way to approach this type of query. In most SQL dialects, you can leave out the 'ELSE 0' section, but there is no good reason to do so.

Comment: @LaughingVergil Valid point regarding Else 0.   For me if not a muscle-memory thing, it is just more readable and you won't get a NULL value if the condition is never met.

Comment: From SQL 2012 onwards you could use the IIF statement instead of the CASE statement. E.g. SUM(IIF(<Conditions>, 1, 0)

Comment: @StuKay Yes very true, but there is no performance gain, only eye candy  :)

Answer (score 2):

Try This, it is Tested

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN COUNT(*) ELSE NULL END as conditionalcountall
FROM TABLE
```

`1 = 1`is example conditions

**Demo:-**

```
Create table #temp (id int , col1 varchar (10))
go

insert into #temp values (1 , 'aaaa')
insert into #temp values (2 , 'bbbb')
insert into #temp values (3 , 'cccc')

SELECT
CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN COUNT(*) ELSE NULL END as conditionalcountall
FROM #temp
```

**Result:**

[image]

In Case Condation like that `id = 1` you should `select Count(*)` in `CASE` cluse in your query

like this:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN (select COUNT(*) from  #temp) ELSE NULL END as conditionalcountall
FROM #temp
```

**Result:-**

[image]

**Note**: if You used `Count(*)` directly, you counted the id column, so you should use `group by` as next:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN  COUNT(*) ELSE NULL END as conditionalcountall
FROM #temp
group by id
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ahmed but see original post, I tried that originally and it failed.

Comment: @ProcComment what is the error that you get, plz add an example of real data.

Comment: @ProcComment the answer has been updated via adding a demo.

Comment: it seems you are right. I tested some very simple logic using this method on using my database and it returned a result. Something else in my "real" SELECT/CASE STATEMENT must be causing the issue. I marked the other response as the answer because it has fixed the problem. Thank you for the demo, it's good to see this indeed works.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN X THEN Y
   ELSE Z
   END *NEW COLUMN NAME*
,  COUNT(*)
FROM 
   TABLE
GROUP BY
   *NEW COLUMN NAME*
```

This should return two columns, one with the buckets/case statement and one with the count of the columns for each one of your buckets

This method was the most straightforward for myself

Answer (score -1):

If you REALLY, REALLY want to use `COUNT`, then you can do this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE <conditions>
```